# How to summon credentials from Keychain Access?

Tags: keychain

The website: https://ritx-fl-sales.bswa.net has username / password fields:

[image]

For some reason the fields do not prompt Keychain access.   Is there a work-around to summoning the password manager to type a selected username/pw credential into their respective fields?

Comment: You might be able to persuade Auto-fill to do it. I have two sites like that - my bank & my council office. For one I can click the autofill button, the other I have to manually open Keychain Access then copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

The reason those fields do not prompt Keychain access is that the developer of the web site has done it incorrectly (unless they were intentionally aiming to avoid people using password managers).

Basically in order to prompt Keychain access, the developer needs to mark the fields as being for username/password. They can do that explicitly using the `autocomplete` attribute, which they can set to `username`, `password` or even `new-password` when you want to create a new password. It can also be done implicitly merely by having the name of the input field be `username`and `password` (or `user` and `pass` and similar variants).

This particular web site has some odd name choices for the fields, as they have named them `txtUserID` and `txtPassword`.

Luckily they have marked the `password` field as being a `password` type (meaning that the entered text should not be viewed) - therefore you should be able to click on the password field to focus it, and then click the small key icon that appears on right in the field. From there you can select to fill password from Keychain.

Comment: Excellent explanation and good catch with the `password` enabled field.  Ideally I would be able to select the `username` field and somehow prompt & indicate to fill in the username.

Comment: @gatorback You can't without changing the web page - but why not select the `password` field? - That would be just as easy. If you want you can install a browser extension that would change the code in the web site, but it is a bit tedious unless you use that site often.